# How to SUM part of a UNIQUE ARRAY formula

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, sum

Hi I can't figure this out for the life of me! On the second tab 'Combined' I'm trying to get the array to show a combination of unique dates, names and then a total of the amount to pay that person.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sSuHK0h2OeaEJpraoHXTi01XIwpreM47BovQAV-snDE/edit?usp=sharing

So ideally it should show on the 'Combined' page:

```
                        A
```

1. 11/15/2020 Bill Jones $553.80
2. 11/15/2020 Steve Robinson $320.00
3. 10/7/2019 Grady Johnson $100.12
4. 11/15/2020 Grady Johnson $45.00
5. 11/22/2020 Jim Luke $300.43
6. 11/17/2020 Jim Luke $1,357.63

I've been trying to figure this out for days - please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
=QUERY(Investors!A4:C, 
 "select A,B,sum(C) 
  where A is not null
  group by A,B
  label sum(C)''")
```

[image]

Comment: You sir - are my hero! Thank you thank you thank you thank you. I can't thank you enough. I was looking at the problem wrong... You just clarified it. Again, THANK YOU!

Comment: Unfortunately it won't let me upvote your answer because I'm new. But you've definitely shown me the value of this site. I'll be around much more (with answers as well as questions).